# Arduino sketch not uploading to UNO R3

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I bought my first board (not original) that uses a CH340 chipset. I installed the driver for it, as well as the Arduino IDE. When I try to upload for example the "Fade" sketch, I get the following error message: `avrdude stk500_recv() programmer is not responding`.

I saw that some are able to select the “ATmego328P (Old Bootloader)” processor from Tools->Processor, but the IDE version that I installed doesn't have it. Is the board broken?

Comment: "ATmego328P (Old Bootloader)" is only for Arduino Nano. The Uno has only one version of bootloader (the 'new' one)

Comment: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/17/avrdude-stk500-getsync-not-in-sync-resp-0x00-aka-some-dude-named-avr-won

Answer (score 0):

the microcontroller is not accepting the code because it is not ATMEGA328 so u can go with the assembly-level program to code it.